# How to convert a Saxon transformer to W3C document

Tags: xslt, document, transformation, w3c, saxon

I am using Saxon 9.4 HE to transform a W3C Document object by turning it into a DomSource like so:

```
  Processor processor = new Processor(false);
  XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
  XsltExecutable executable = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
  XsltTransformer transformer = executable.load();
  transformer.setSource(new DOMSource(doc));
  StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
  Serializer output = new Serializer(buffer);
  transformer.setDestination(output);
  transformer.transform();
```

I want to received result of the transformation to be a W3C Document object, is there any way to that, without using buffer.toString() to create a new Document object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/DOMDestination.html so you should be able to provide a DOMDestination. I haven't checked however if Saxon HE comes with DOMDestination, it might be that only PE and EE provide that flexibility. And Michael Kay always points out that using the DOM with Saxon is inefficient compared to Saxon's native tree implementation so consider whether you do not want to use that instead of the W3C DOM.

Comment: Hi Michael,Thanks for the answer. The problem is that eventually I do need a W3C dom for post processing ingestion. 

Do you know if it there's an efficient way to convert the result to a W3C DOM?

Comment: If you really need a W3C DOM then try DOMDestination. As an alternative way you could check whether creating a Saxon NodeInfo result which you wrap as http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/html/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/dom/DocumentOverNodeInfo.html with e.g. `Document doc = (Document)DocumentOverNodeInfo.wrap(someNodeInfo);` performs better.

Comment: Using a DOMDestination is correct, and works with all Saxon editions. The remarks about DOM with Saxon being inefficient relate more to using a DOM as input; creating a DOM as output shouldn't be too bad.